# Django async nested model loading

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

I have models:

```py
class ObjectA(models.Model):
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    objectb = models.ForeignKey(ObjectB, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "objecta"

class ObjectB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    objectc = models.ForeignKey(ObjectC, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "objectb"

class ObjectC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "objectc"
```

In my `ViewSet` function I want to get `ObjectA` and then get name from referenced `ObjectC`.

In synchronous Django I would do

```py
get_object_or_404(ObjectA, alias="My alias").objectb.objectc.name
```

But this in async Django throws me an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

I found a solution which does not look very clean to me:

```py
from django.db.models.query import aprefetch_related_objects
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

get_objecta_model = sync_to_async(get_object_or_404, thread_sensitive=True)
objecta = await get_objecta_model(ObjectA, name=alias)

await aprefetch_related_objects([objecta], "objectb__objectc")

objecta.objectb.objectc.name
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge this is one of the workarounds you could currently use. Deferred lookups are not supported in async mode.

Another method would be to use an explicit `.aget` with `.select_related` instead of using the `get_object_or_404` helper:

```py
try:
    objecta = await ObjectA.objects.select_related("objectb__objectc").aget(name="foo")
    objectc_name = objecta.objectb.objectc.name
except ObjectA.DoesNotFound:
    return HttpResponseNotFound()
```